# estimote beacons - could not bind service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

i try to develop app with using Becons. I have [this](http://estimote.com/) small Estimote Beacon. I made steps described in [this](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) short instruction. I downloaded the library from [github](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/EstimoteSDK), I added it to myproject.

My code look like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 BeaconManager beaconManager;

  private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
  private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region(ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);

  final String TAG = "MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());

    if(beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bl włączone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bl wyłączone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

      beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ranged beacons: " + beacons, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
      });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.e(TAG, "onStart");
    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override public void onServiceReady() {
          try {
            beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try start ranging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging", e);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot start ranging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }
      });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
      // Should be invoked in #onStop.
      try {
        beaconManager.stopRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot stop but it does not matter now", e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot stop but it does not matter now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
     // When no longer needed. Should be invoked in #onDestroy.
      beaconManager.disconnect();
}
```

}

and manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.beacon"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

 <!-- Needed permissions in order to scan for beacons. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

 <!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" 
    android:required="true"/>

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
     android:exported="false"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.beacon.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>           
       </activity>        
   < /application>
</manifest>
```

showed on the page and I get this message

```
02-22 05:27:08.711: A/BeaconManager(7227): Could not bind service
```

For me it means like it's problem with creating BeaconManager, but have no idea how to fix it. There is no problem with device cause I see all beacons when I scanned it by `iBeacon Locate` app. I would be grateful for any suggestion

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to use the Estimote SDK, but since you know the iBeacon Locate app works, you might try the Android iBeacon Library on which it is based.  The key benefit of this library is that it is open source so it is easier to get community  help if problems arise. http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/  full disclosure: I am the author of the library.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try this library ;) thx for this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Estimote SDK are you using? Is it the newest 0.4 version? Checking it as newest has different log tags.

If logs says "Could not bind service" that means that `com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService` could not have been found. Note that early version of the SDK `BeaconService` was in `com.estimote.sdk` package and not in `com.estimote.sdk.service` one.

BTW were you able to run Demos in the Estimote SDK?

Comment: Yeah, I have the newest version of sdk 0.4. My imports from this estimote for this activity import com.estimote.sdk.Beacon;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager;
import com.estimote.sdk.Region;   I didn't try to run the demos

Comment: I change the log in manifest from com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService to com.estimote.sdk.BeaconService and I think it works